# What does the create_additions option do in JSON.parse

Tags: ruby, json

I came across the `create_additions` option in rubys JSON.parse docs but I can't seem to find any documentation about it.

The rdoc describes the option with:

> create_additions: If set to false, the Parser doesn't 
>   create additions even if a matching class and ::create_id was found. 
>   This option defaults to true.

Out of curiosity, can anyone explain what this option actually does and what this "additions" feature of JSON.parse is anyways?

Comment: JSON stands for JavasScript Object Notation. I could think of a JSON string which consists of multiple objects, like parent <-> child relationships. Maybe the 'create_additions' is creating the child objects as well if set to true? But actually, I am just guessing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "additions" are additions to pure JSON. If a hash has the `json_class` key (customizable with [`JSON.create_id`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#create_id)), it is deserialized as that class instead of a plain hash.

Comment: beautiful. Although a minor case of RTFM on my side. Didn't look for the create_id attribute, duh. thank you!